# How to include dependency repos on published android library

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, maven-repository

I am working on a library that uses custom repositories (i.e. with specific URLs) to get some of the dependencies.

```
maven { 
            url 'https://someURL/'
        }
```

I've published the library and set it on our private repository and noticed that I couldn't compile because gradle couldn't locate these dependencies. I could fix that by adding the same custom repositories to the testing app project-level build.gradle, but I want to know if there's an option to avoid this, meaning, have the testing application get the custom repositories information from the published packages.